# Java return statement logic with a Binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to understand how the return statement on the main insert method substitutes the null value for the created node when the first condition is true.

```
 public void insert(int input){
        insert(root, input);
    }
}

public Node insert(Node node, int key) {
    if (node == null) {
        return new Node(key);
    } else if (node.key > key) {
        node.left = insert(node.left, key);
    } else if (node.key < key) {
        node.right = insert(node.right, key);
    } else {
        return node;
    }
}
```

My understanding of how the return statement works is that it stops a function and returns a value. Hence, in this situation, a new node is created with key as it's data, then that node is returned. Is there some other thing the return statement does?

Comment: This code looks incorrect. There should probably also be a `root = ...` to actually change the tree and really insert the node. The code right now indeed just generates a new node and returns it, but never adds it to anything. The tree is not changed and hence the insert basically didnt do anything meaningful. Also, it is missing `return` statements in the other branches. Sure it is meant to return anything? I do not think so.

Comment: Does this code compile? Your understanding of `return` appears to be correct, but the `else if` and `else` branches should also have `return` statements, and they don't.

Comment: Apart from that it won't compile because it's missing return statements, if `root` already exists, then this would add a node to your tree, but if `root` does not already exist, this will do nothing.

Comment: To add to that: most likely `root` will intially be `null` thus `root = insert(root, input);` would make sense but only if `insert(Node node, int key)` returns `node` in all cases other than `node == null`. In the current state, even after the edit, the code would not compile since _all_ paths need to return a value (or throw an exception).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I get there will still be a compile error. My final return statement should have been after the if else block, my bad. But my confusion stems from how the return statement can substitute the null value (i.e. when root is null) to the created node without any form of assignment

Comment: Well, the code you've posted doesn't change `root` itself so if it is `null` it will stay null. However, there's clearly more to that class so if it works `root` should be initialized in some other way - maybe even in the constructor/initializer block so it never is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code, and together these problems might explain why you’re having trouble understanding the role of `return`.

1. Your `insert(input)` method ignores the return value of its `insert(node, key)` call. This means that if `root` is `null`, nothing will be inserted into the three
2. Your `insert(node, key)` method does not return values on all code paths. This means the code won’t even compile, and also won’t be correct.

The fixed code might look as follows:

```
public void insert(int input) {
    root = insert(root, input); // 1
}

public Node insert(Node node, int key) {
    if (node == null) {
        return new Node(key);
    }

    if (node.key > key) {
        node.left = insert(node.left, key);
    } else if (node.key < key) {
        node.right = insert(node.right, key);
    }

    return node; // 2
}
```

This simply makes sure that the current node is always returned after the insertion took place (recursively), or if no insertion took place because the value already existed.

Now the `return` logic should make sense.

Comment: Thank you Konrad for the correction on the code. My confusion however is how the first return statement substitutes the null value for the node object (i.e. when root is null). I am thinking it should only create a new node and return it without an assignment. Thanks again

Comment: @alexolakpe As you said: “it should only create a new node and return it without an assignment.” That is exactly what happens. The return statement doesn’t “substitute” anything: it simply returns a newly-created node. The assignment of that new node is done by the *caller*.